# how can I restrict the keys of an object to be the values of an object?

Tags: typescript

I have an object defined with string keys and number values:

```
class MyService {
  private static readonly MAPPING: { [ index: string ]: number } = {
    a: 16,
    b: 32,
  };
}
```

And I would like to have another object that only allows the values (numbers) defined in that mapping as keys

```
class MyService {
  private static readonly MAPPING: { [ index: string ]: number } = {
    a: 16,
    b: 32,
  } as const;
  public static states: { [ index in ?!? (Object.values(MyService.MAPPING)) ?!? ]: boolean } = {}; // <-- clearly this is wrong
}
```

So that:
`MyService.states[16] = true` would be valid, but `MyService.states[17] = true` would not.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not allowed to define a type within a class, you will have to define the type using the constant object on the root level of the file and use it in your class.

```js
const MAPPING = {
  a: 16,
  b: 32,
} as const;

type MAPPING_VALUE = typeof MAPPING[keyof typeof MAPPING];

class MyService {
  public static readonly MAPPING: { [index: string]: number } = MAPPING;
  public static states: {
    [index in MAPPING_VALUE]: boolean;
  } = {
    16: true,
    32: false,
  };
}
```

Comment: For initialization, we can restrict access by union types, but for value access, we can't do that. In other words `MyService.states[44] = true;` will be also valid due to dynamic property search. For dot notation, we need a valid identifier, like this `$16`.

Comment: i've just tried it and it seems it's not like you described

`MyService.states[16] = true`
 is valid according to ts, but  `typescript MyService.states[44]= true` isn't.

Comment: Interesting..  Thank you.  I still am getting used to the idea of having things like that defined outside of classes, that has always felt "wrong" to do.

Comment: in case you use a type that doesn't belong to your MAPPING values you will see (eg: 17):

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '17' can't be used to index type '{ 16: boolean; 32: boolean; }'.
  Property '17' does not exist on type '{ 16: boolean; 32: boolean; }'.`